# ClaimsPrincipal.HttpContext in .Net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-5

I am attempting to mock IPrinciple (as i had a controller action which used `User.Identity.Name`, for which I would like to write unit test for) in my Unit Test(using .net 5 preview). Refering to answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557942/mocking-iprincipal-in-asp-net-core), I have the following in my Unit Test.

```
var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName),
               
}, "mock"));
userController.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext()
{
                 
    HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext() { User = user }
};
```

However, I recieve following error.

```
Reference to type 'HttpContextBase' claims it is defined in 'System.Web', but it could not be found
```

I saw a similiar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52374873/reference-to-type-httpcontextbase-claims-it-is-defined-in-system-web-but-it), but the answer directs to change the target version. I was wondering if there was a way out without changing target version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally managed to solve it, leaving the answer here for anyone who might face a similar situation.

Instead of replacing the `ControllerContext` completely, I replaced `ControllerContext.HttpContext`

```cs
var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName),
               
}, "mock"));
userController.ControllerContext.HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext() { User = user };
```

This ensured the Controller could receive UserName with

```cs
var userName = User.Identity.Name;
```